# O que o Prepare do PDO faz quando o utilizamos?

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

O que exatamente o prepare faz?

Por exemplo, ele criptografa, ou alguma coisa assim? Porque, sendo sincero, eu uso o método, mas nunca entendi muito bem o seu uso.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <?php
        $a = new PDO(); //Imaginem que minhas infos estão aqui
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tableusers";
        $a->prepare($query);
        $a->execute();
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

No caso ali, sem usar o prepare funcionaria do mesmo modo. Ou não? Ele executa o que "por baixo dos panos"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a documentação do PHP em [php.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepare.php)

> Chamar PDO :: prepare () e PDOStatement :: execute () para instruções que serão emitidas várias vezes com valores de parâmetros diferentes otimiza o desempenho de seu aplicativo, permitindo que o driver negocie o cache do cliente e / ou servidor do plano de consulta e meta informações e ajuda a evitar ataques de injeção de SQL, eliminando a necessidade de citar manualmente os parâmetros.

Ele ajuda a evitar a injeção SQL separando o comando dos parâmetros, tratando os parâmetros informados pelo usuário como texto puro.

Leia mais em: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepare.php